# Interpretation of data for Market Premium

Tags: spread, default-probability

I am given some preliminary data with a goal to estimate the `probability of default`. This data consists of Market premium for different tenors.

One such example read that, Market `Premium (Running and Up-front)` for tenor 5 years are 1.40% and 0%. Similarly the `Market Premium (Running and Up-front)` for tenor 8 years are 1.55% and 0%.

I am curious what this data means? Is the `Running Market Premium` basically Credit Spread value for that particular tenor? What then is the meaning of `Up-front Market premium`?

Any pointer is very appreciated.